# How to change color of bitmap without paint bucket

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an image I need the text to be white and also in silver.

Is there a way to maybe mask the image or use one of the adjustment tools to color the whole image? Instead of using something like paint bucket which wouldn't pick up the distressed detail.

[image]

Comment: You have the right idea... paint bucket is never the tool you want to use. Use masking and filling.

Comment: Wait I'm confused. You want to color the text or the background? It seems the text is already on a transparent layer and you already added an adjustment layer, so what exactly is the issue? If you want to have 2 versions of the image (1 white and 1 silver) can't you just duplicate the adjustment layers and show/hide when exporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paint bucket often doesn't fill areas as wanted, the edges can become more or less trashy. Photoshop has better tools for recoloring.

Seemingly your text already is a bitmap image and you have inserted a B&W adjustment layer, maybe to remove all color or to get the white and silver. The latter is impossible with B&W if there's only dark shades.

I would insert a new adjustment layer "Curves". With it you can invert black to white and create metallic effects if there's some greyscale gradients. As an adjustment layer it's non-destructive, so experiment freely. By having the "next layer only" switch =ON you can keep possible underlying layers intact.

An example: Black text on dark color background needs lightening:

[image]

With curves one can lift black to grey or white. This time the text has only black and transparency, so more variations are impossible with curves:

[image]

The "next layer only" -switch is ON to save the background.

With adjustment layer Hue&Saturation you can also affect colors. It can turn everything to grayscale, cause color shifts and colorize with a wanted color. I guess it's useless just in this case.

You should learn layer masks and layer styles. By having a white text on black in the layer mask you can for example make the text appear to be clipped from any material. Only get a photo of that material and put the text to the layer mask. With layer style Bevel & Emboss one creates metallic and 3D thickness effects with nearly zero effort. Drop shadow creates layer separation etc,etc,etc....

Here the preceding adjustment layer is merged to fix the effect. Layer style Bevel&Emboss creates some apparent thickness:

[image]

Comment: This got me where I needed to go for the most part, however I also need to convert this to gold and am not sure what the best way to get there is. Curves worked great for silver.

Comment: I was interestd in gold, too a moment. Check this and get some ideas: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uuty3z7tyn40vvw/Nier%20Orchestra.psd?dl=0